# setSlaveOkay is deprecated?

Tags: php, mongodb

I received this error message:

> Deprecated: Function Mongo::setSlaveOkay() is deprecated

In the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.setslaveokay.php), it says:

> MongoCollection::setSlaveOkay
>
> (PECL mongo >=1.1.0)
>
> MongoCollection::setSlaveOkay — Change slaveOkay setting for this
>   collection

I couldn't find anything mentioned about it being deprecated.

My PHP version is 5.3.10 and MongoDB version is 1.3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answers state `setSlaveOkay` has been deprecated in favour of full read preferences ( http://derickrethans.nl/readpreferences.html ). This was a change made when the `MongoClient` class was introduced ( http://derickrethans.nl/mongoclient.html ).

If you look towards the bottom of the PHP manual page ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.setslaveokay.php ) you will see a changelog section whereby it mentions:

> Emits E_DEPRECATED when used.

The "See Also" section below that one provides links to what replaces it, read preferences.

As backup Hannes ( https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/CAWuND9niLo ), one of the maintainers, mentions:

> We wanted to prepare people that the preferred way [...] will change in the upcoming 1.3.0 release (scheduled "soon").

So yes, from now on you should be using read preferences.

Answer (score 2):

'slaveOk' has been replaced with the more configurable ReadPreferences capability.

Here is the introduction for PHP ReadReferences:

> MongoDB 2.2 and version 1.3.0 of the driver add support for read
>   preferences, which allow control over how queries are directed to
>   mongod instances in a replica set environment. Read preferences may be
>   specified on either a per-connection, per-database, or per-collection
>   basis. Preferences defined at a higher level will be inherited by
>   default (e.g. MongoCollection will inherit read perferences defined on
>   the corresponding MongoDB instance).
>
> Read preferences are specified with a combination of modes and tag
>   sets. Modes determine how mongod instances are prioritized, while
>   tag sets specify criteria for eligible mongod instances.

http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.readpreferences.php

HTH - Rob

Comment: $d->setReadPreference( Mongo::RP_PRIMARY_PREFERRED );$m->setReadPreference( Mongo::RP_SECONDARY_PREFERRED );

Answer (score 0):

The PHP changelog for this function

1.2.11  Emits E_DEPRECATED when used.

so it is deprecated for the pecl mongo driver.